# How to create transaction with isolation level in SQL

Tags: sql, db2, transaction-isolation

How to create a transaction with isolation level in SQL.

I'v tried something like this, but obviously it does not work:

```
INSERT INTO test(col1) VALUES ('test')
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL read stability;
COMMIT WORK;
```

I'm using SQL DB2 LUW

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=information-sqlj-set-transaction-clause says:

> You can execute SET TRANSACTION only at the beginning of a transaction.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.5?topic=statements-set-transaction says:

> The SET TRANSACTION statement can only be executed when it is the
> first SQL statement in a unit of work, unless:
>
> - all previous statements executed in the unit of work are SET
>   TRANSACTION statements or statements that are executed under isolation
>   level NC, or
> - it is executed in a trigger.

I'm not a user of DB2, but this seems to say that you must SET TRANSACTION before your INSERT. This matches my experience in other RDBMS products.

Comment: Thank you but that does not work too, it might be that my approach is wrong because I'm getting a syntax error

Comment: `SET TRANSACTION... ;`  is one statement.  `INSERT ... ;`  is a second.  `COMIT;` is yet a third.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [SET CURRENT ISOLATION statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-set-current-isolation).